# Dbimport utility missing in informix docker image?

Tags: docker, informix, dbimport

I am trying to import data exported from remote instance of informix database into my local docker instance, but there is no dbimport in /opt/ibm/informix/bin inside the docker container. I didn't find anything about this anywhere. Am I missing something? It sure feels like that... Thanks.

Comment: `ontape` and `onbar` are also missing in 'ibmcom' images. Did you solved your problem?

Comment: well, I planned on making my own image based purely on ubuntu, but I didn't get to since the need for it simply cease to exist

Comment: Ah. "since the need for it simply cease to exist" - same for me but who knows maybe in future the need will arise again

Comment: That future is today @AlexYu :)